# Find poles of $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)^2}$ , calculate residues at the poles and then evaluate $\int_C f(z)dz$ where $C:|z+1-i|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

The poles are clearly 1 and 2. $C$ is the circle with equation $(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2=4$. Putting $y=0$, we get $x=\sqrt{3} -1, -\sqrt{3} - 1$. This means both poles lie outside the circle. So both residues are zero. The integral is $2\pi i$ times sum of residues, so it's also zero.

Is my work correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: The residues of $f$ at $1$ and $2$ are not zero. But you are right, since $1$ and $2$ are outside $C$, it follows that the integral is zero.

Comment: So far so good...but what are the function's residues at those poles? They definitely are not zero: the integral is! And also: this is an elementary question to practice, I'd say, the Residue Theorem. Are you sure that $\;C\;$ is what you say it is?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes I checked $C$ is exactly that. Maybe this question is supposed to be very easy. Also, how are the residues not zero if the points are outside the curve?

Answer (score 0):

For a rational function with pole $0$,you simply obtain its *Laurent's expansion* dividing by increasing powers its numerator by its  denominator.

For a pole $\alpha\ne 0$, you first use the substitution $u=z-\alpha$, to obtain a rational function in $u$, with pole $0$.

I'll show how it runs for the pole $2$ of $f(z)$. So we set $u=z-2$ and
$$f(z)=\frac{2+u}{(1+u)u^2}=g(u).$$
Now to the division:

\begin{alignat}{4}
\dfrac2{u^2} &-\dfrac 1u&{}+{}&1&{}-{}&u +\dotsm \\
u^2+u^3\Bigm( \phantom{-}2&+u \\
-2&-2u \\[-2ex]
- &--\\[-2ex]
&-u\\
&+u &{}+{}&u^2 \\[-1ex]
&---&-&-\\[-1ex]
&&{}-{}&u^2&{}-{}&u^3\\[-1ex]
&&&---&-\\[-1ex]
&&&&{}-{}&u^3\\[-1ex]
&&&&&\ddots
\end{alignat}
Therefor the residue  at pole $2$ is equal to $-1$.